# Inconsistent result from sphinxsearch when doing geo distance search

Tags: sphinx

I have an application that uses sphinxsearch and have a situation in which there needs to do some searching based on distance, like within 1 mile, 5 mile, 20 miles, 100 miles. It works fine on most occasions. But sometimes, suppose if we search for data within 20 miles and say we have 5 result data, it returns correctly. Next, if we do a search within 100 miles, it returns fewer data compared to the 20 mile search. However, this is fixed if we re-index the data and try the search again. After re-indexing, it runs well for some days.

Anybody knows why this happens and how to fix it ?

**sphinx.conf:**

```
source src1
{

type                    = mysql

#####################################################################
## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
#####################################################################

# some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
sql_host                = localhost
sql_user                = my_user
sql_pass                = my_pass
sql_db                  = my_db
sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306



# main document fetch query
# mandatory, integer document ID field MUST be the first selected column
sql_query               = \
    SELECT 1000000000000000+id as id , name, NULL as address, keywords as keyword, 1 as type \
    FROM tbl1 \
            UNION \
        SELECT 2000000000000000+id as id , name, address, NULL as keyword, 2 as type  \
    FROM tbl2 \
    UNION \
        SELECT 3000000000000000+id as id , name, NULL as address, NULL as keyword, 3 as type  \
    FROM tbl3 \
    UNION \
        SELECT 4000000000000000+id as id , name, NULL as address, NULL as keyword, 4 as type  \
    FROM tbl4

    sql_field_string = name
    sql_attr_uint = type
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0 
}

source filter_tbl1
{

type                    = mysql

#####################################################################
## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
#####################################################################

# some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
sql_host                = localhost
sql_user                = my_user
sql_pass                = my_pass
sql_db                  = my_db
sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306



# main document fetch query
# mandatory, integer document ID field MUST be the first selected column
sql_query               = \
    SELECT CONCAT(t1.id,t5.cid) as id, t1.id as t1id, c.name AS cname, latitude * pi() / 180 as latitude, \
    longitude * pi() / 180 as longitude, 1 as type FROM `tbl1` AS t1 \
    JOIN  tbl5 AS t5 ON t5.etId = t1.id JOIN tbl4 AS c ON t5.cid  = c.id   \
            LEFT JOIN `tbl2` AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.locationId JOIN `tbl6` AS cc ON t2.cityId = cc.id   \
    WHERE t1.isPublic='yes' AND t1.active ='yes' AND endDate >= CURDATE()


    sql_field_string = t1id
sql_field_string = cname
    sql_attr_float = latitude
    sql_attr_float = longitude
sql_attr_uint = type
sql_ranged_throttle = 0 
}

source filter_active
{

type                    = mysql

#####################################################################
## SQL settings (for 'mysql' and 'pgsql' types)
#####################################################################

# some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
sql_host                = localhost
sql_user                = my_user
sql_pass                = my_pass
sql_db                  = my_db
sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306



# main document fetch query
# mandatory, integer document ID field MUST be the first selected column
sql_query               = \
    SELECT t1.id as id, t1.isPublic as isPublic, t1.active as active, latitude * pi() / 180 as latitude, longitude * pi() / 180 as longitude, \
            1 as type \
    FROM `tbl1` AS t1 \
            JOIN  tbl5 AS t5 ON t5.etId = t1.id JOIN tbl4 AS c ON t5.cid = c.id  \
    LEFT JOIN `tbl2` AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.locationId JOIN `tbl6` AS cc ON t2.cityId = cc.id   \
    WHERE t1.isPublic='yes' AND t1.active ='yes' AND endDate >= CURDATE()


sql_field_string = isPublic
sql_field_string = active
sql_attr_float = latitude
    sql_attr_float = longitude
sql_attr_uint  = type
sql_ranged_throttle = 0 
}

source src1throttled : src1
{
sql_ranged_throttle         = 100
}
source filter_tbl1throttled : filter_tbl1
{
sql_ranged_throttle         = 100
}
source filter_activethrottled : filter_active
{
sql_ranged_throttle         = 100
}

index loop_srch_local
{

source          = src1
path            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/loop_srch_local

min_prefix_len      = 1
    # min_infix_len     = 1
enable_star     = 1
expand_keywords         = 1 
    prefix_fields = name, address, keyword
    dict            = keywords
charset_type = utf-8
}

index loop_srch
{    
    type = rt

    path = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/loop_srch   

min_prefix_len      = 2
    # min_infix_len     = 1
enable_star     = 1
expand_keywords         = 1 
    prefix_fields           = name, address, keyword
    dict            = keywords
    charset_type = utf-8


    # rt_attr_bigint = id  
    rt_field = name
    rt_field = address
    rt_field = keyword
    rt_attr_uint = type
}

index loop_filt_tabl1
{    
    type = rt

    path = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/loop_filt_tabl1

 rt_field = t1id    
 rt_field = cname
 rt_attr_float = latitude
 rt_attr_float = longitude
 rt_attr_uint = type

dict            = keywords
min_word_len        = 3
#min_prefix_len     = 3
    min_infix_len       = 1
enable_star     = 1
html_strip      = 0
inplace_enable      = 0

    charset_type = utf-8
}

index loop_filt_tbl1_local
{

source          = filter_tbl1
path            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/filter_tbl1_local

dict            = keywords
min_word_len        = 3
#min_prefix_len     = 3
    min_infix_len       = 1
enable_star     = 1
html_strip      = 0
inplace_enable      = 0

    charset_type = utf-8

}

index loop_filt_active
{    
    type = rt

     path = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/loop_filt_active

 rt_field = isPublic
 rt_field =  active
 rt_attr_float = latitude
 rt_attr_float = longitude
 rt_attr_uint = type

dict            = keywords
min_word_len        = 3
#min_prefix_len     = 3
    min_infix_len       = 1
enable_star     = 1
html_strip      = 0
inplace_enable      = 0

    charset_type = utf-8
}

index loop_filt_active_local
{

source          = filter_active
path            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/filter_active_local

dict            = keywords
min_word_len        = 3
#min_prefix_len     = 3
    min_infix_len       = 1
enable_star     = 1
html_strip      = 0
inplace_enable      = 0

    charset_type = utf-8
}


index loop_srchstemmed : loop_srch_local
{
path            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/loop_srchstemmed
morphology      = stem_en
}

index dist1
{
# 'distributed' index type MUST be specified
type                = distributed

# local index to be searched
# there can be many local indexes configured
local               = loop_srch_local
local               = loop_srchstemmed
local               = loop_filt_tabl1_local
local               = loop_filt_active_local    

# remote agent
# multiple remote agents may be specified
# syntax for TCP connections is 'hostname:port:index1,[index2[,...]]'
# syntax for local UNIX connections is '/path/to/socket:index1,[index2[,...]]'
agent               = localhost:9313:remote1
agent               = localhost:9314:remote2,remote3
# agent             = /var/run/searchd.sock:remote4

# blackhole remote agent, for debugging/testing
# network errors and search results will be ignored
#
# agent_blackhole       = testbox:9312:testindex1,testindex2


# remote agent connection timeout, milliseconds
# optional, default is 1000 ms, ie. 1 sec
agent_connect_timeout   = 1000

# remote agent query timeout, milliseconds
# optional, default is 3000 ms, ie. 3 sec
agent_query_timeout     = 3000
}

indexer
{
# memory limit, in bytes, kiloytes (16384K) or megabytes (256M)
# optional, default is 32M, max is 2047M, recommended is 256M to 1024M
mem_limit           = 32M

# maximum IO calls per second (for I/O throttling)
# optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
#
# max_iops          = 40


# maximum IO call size, bytes (for I/O throttling)
# optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
#
# max_iosize        = 1048576


# maximum xmlpipe2 field length, bytes
# optional, default is 2M
#
# max_xmlpipe2_field    = 4M


# write buffer size, bytes
# several (currently up to 4) buffers will be allocated
# write buffers are allocated in addition to mem_limit
# optional, default is 1M
#
# write_buffer      = 1M
}

searchd
{
# hostname, port, or hostname:port, or /unix/socket/path to listen on
# multi-value, multiple listen points are allowed
# optional, default is 0.0.0.0:9312 (listen on all interfaces, port 9312)
#
# listen                = 127.0.0.1
listen              = 0.0.0.0:9312
listen              = 9306:mysql41
# listen                = /var/run/searchd.sock


# log file, searchd run info is logged here
# optional, default is 'searchd.log'
log                 = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.log

# query log file, all search queries are logged here
# optional, default is empty (do not log queries)
query_log           = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/query.log

# client read timeout, seconds
# optional, default is 5
read_timeout        = 5

# request timeout, seconds
# optional, default is 5 minutes
client_timeout      = 300

# maximum amount of children to fork (concurrent searches to run)
# optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
max_children        = 30

# PID file, searchd process ID file name
# mandatory
pid_file            = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
#pid_file           = /var/run/sphinx-searchd.pid

# max amount of matches the daemon ever keeps in RAM, per-index
# WARNING, THERE'S ALSO PER-QUERY LIMIT, SEE SetLimits() API CALL
# default is 1000 (just like Google)
max_matches         = 1000

# seamless rotate, prevents rotate stalls if precaching huge datasets
# optional, default is 1
seamless_rotate     = 1

# whether to forcibly preopen all indexes on startup
# optional, default is 0 (do not preopen)
preopen_indexes     = 0

# whether to unlink .old index copies on succesful rotation.
# optional, default is 1 (do unlink)
unlink_old          = 1

# attribute updates periodic flush timeout, seconds
# updates will be automatically dumped to disk this frequently
# optional, default is 0 (disable periodic flush)
#
# attr_flush_period = 900


# instance-wide ondisk_dict defaults (per-index value take precedence)
# optional, default is 0 (precache all dictionaries in RAM)
#
# ondisk_dict_default   = 1


# MVA updates pool size
# shared between all instances of searchd, disables attr flushes!
# optional, default size is 1M
mva_updates_pool    = 1M

# max allowed network packet size
# limits both query packets from clients, and responses from agents
# optional, default size is 8M
max_packet_size     = 8M

# crash log path
# searchd will (try to) log crashed query to 'crash_log_path.PID' file
# optional, default is empty (do not create crash logs)
#
# crash_log_path        = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/crash


# max allowed per-query filter count
# optional, default is 256
max_filters         = 256

# max allowed per-filter values count
# optional, default is 4096
max_filter_values   = 4096


# socket listen queue length
# optional, default is 5
#
# listen_backlog        = 5


# per-keyword read buffer size
# optional, default is 256K
#
# read_buffer           = 256K


# unhinted read size (currently used when reading hits)
# optional, default is 32K
#
# read_unhinted     = 32K
    workers               = threads
}
```

**client code**

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SphinxClient();
$cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$cl->SetRankingMode( SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 );

$latitudeRadians  = $latitude*pi()/180 ; // some value for $latitude
$longitudeRadians = $longitude*pi()/180 ;// some value for $longitude
$cl->SetGeoAnchor('venue_latitude', 'venue_longitude', $latitudeRadians, $longitudeRadians);

$minLimit  = 0.00 ;
$maxLimit  = 15*1609.344 ; //for within 15 miles. Will vary depending on the choice.

$cl->SetFilterFloatRange('@geodist', floatval($minLimit), floatval($maxLimit));
$result = $cl->Query("","loop_filt_tabl1");
```

Comment: You havn't provided enough details to even begin to guess at the cause. How are your indexes defined, how do you reindex them? What exact query are you running etc

Comment: I have updated the details a bit.